# IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed in Django

Tags: django

I have two models, Question and Answer. I am getting this error when I try to add an answer from user side. (adding from admin panel is okay). I have gone through few solutions in stackoverflow and other site. I everytime I deleted existing database and ran migrations, but nothing worked. Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    author                  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title                   = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    optional_description    = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date            = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date          = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    question            = models.ForeignKey('ask.Question', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    author              = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text                = models.TextField()
    created_date        = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_answer     = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def approve(self):
        self.approved_answer = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

relevant section from
views.py

```
def add_answer_to_que(request, pk):
    que = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            answer = form.save(commit=False)
            answer.que = que
            answer.save()
            return redirect('ques_detail', pk=que.pk)
    else:
        form = AnswerForm()
    return render(request, 'ask/add_answer_to_que.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('author', 'text',)
```

[image]

Clicking writing an answer button leads to This page

[image]

But after adding something and clicking send leads to this error.

[image]

Comment: I think `answer.question = que`  instead of `answer.que = que`

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Most of the time I got stuck at these silly mistakes of myself and looking for big solutions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in line `answer.que = que`.

just change that line to `answer.question = que`

As you don't have any column named `que` in `Answer` table.

Hope it helps.